# How to concatenate files that have the same beginning of a name?

Tags: regex, loops, unix, bioinformatics, pattern-recognition

I have a directory with a few hundred *.fasta files, such as:

```
Bonobo_sp._str01_ABC784267_CDE789456.fasta
Homo_sapiens_cc21_ABC897867_CDE456789.fasta
Homo_sapiens_cc21_ABC893673_CDE753672.fasta 
Gorilla_gorilla_ghjk6789_ABC736522_CDE789456.fasta
Gorilla_gorilla_ghjk6789_ABC627190_CDE891345.fasta
Gorilla_gorilla_ghjk6789_ABC117190_CDE661345.fasta
```

etc.

I want to concatenate files that belong to the same species, so in this case Homo_sapiens_cc21 and Gorilla_gorilla_ghjk6789.

Almost every species has different number of files that I need to concatenate.

I know that I could use a simple loop in unix/linux like:

```
    for f in thesamename.fasta; do
        cat $f >> output.fasta
    done
```

But I don't know how to specify in a loop how should it recognize only files with the same beginning. Making that manually does not make sense at all with hundreds of files.

Does anybody have any idea how could I do that?

Comment: If you know all your basenames and don't mind entering them explicitly, this could be a simple solution, esp. if this is a one-off job: `for f in Homo_sapiens_cc21_*.fasta; do cat $f >> Homo_sapiens_cc21.fasta; done`

Comment: Hi @wwerner! Thank you for your comment. I would do that, but I have ~400 unique names...

Comment: Do all you prefixes share a common pattern, e.g. three parts separated by dashes?

Comment: Is the species ID the first string in fie file name until the first dot? You need to provide the logic to get that information. If it can only be done manually, then there is no way to automate. If it can be automated, some logic has to be followed. Tell us which is this logic.

Comment: @wwerner Yes, that's the case.

Comment: @Poshi, the whole species ID are, for instance Homo_sapiens_cc21, Gorilla_gorilla_ghjk6789, Bonobo_sp._str01 etc.

Comment: So the logic is "get the three first fields separated by underscores"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that the logic behind the naming is that the species are the first three words separated by underscores. I will also assume that there are no blank spaces in the filenames.

A possible strategy could be to get a list of all the species, and then concatenate all the files with that specie/prefix into a single one:

```
for specie in $(ls *.fasta | cut -f1-3 -d_ | sort -u)
do
    cat "$specie"*.fasta > "$specie.fasta"
done
```

In this code, you list all the fasta files, cut the specie ID and generate an unique list of species. Then you traverse this list and, for every specie, concatenate all the files that start with that specie ID into a single file with the specie name.

More robust solutions can be written using `find` and avoiding `ls`, but they are more verbose and potentialy less clear:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' specie
do
    cat "$specie"*.fasta > "$specie.fasta"
done < <(find -maxdepth 1 -name "*.fasta" -print0 | cut -z -f2 -d/ | cut -z -f1-3 -d_ | sort -zu)
```

Comment: I find your solution to be cleaner than mine.

Comment: @Poshi, thank you for providing solutions to my question, I have tested already the 1st one with `ls`, and (no surprisingly) it gives exactly the same output as the one above. You are right, the second solution with `find` is a bit less clear.

Comment: The second solution is less clear because there are many small subtleties, but the use of find and zero-terminated strings make that code work with filenames of any shape, blank spaces included. If you want clarification about something in particular, just ask. I only wrote that solution to give the (my) best answer, more general and robust, to the problem, but too many things to explain.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in my comment above, if you know all your basenames and don't mind entering them explicitly, a simple solution would be

```
for f in Homo_sapiens_cc21_*.fasta; 
    do cat $f >> Homo_sapiens_cc21.fasta; 
done
```

Since this is not the case, you need to find a a common pattern by which to group the output. From your examples (EDIT: and your comment), I looks like this could be three times a word followed by an underscore.

Assuming this pattern is correct, this would probably do what you require:

```
for f in *.fasta; 
    do cat $f >> $(echo $f | awk -F'_' '{print $1"_"$2"_"$3".fasta"}'); 
done
```

Explanation:

1. List all the `*,fasta` files
2. Construct a file name from the prefix. We do this by piping through `awk`, telling it to split the input by `_` (`-F'_'`) and putting it back together (`'{print $1"_"$2"_"$3".fasta"}'`)
3. Finally we `cat` the current file and redirect the output to the newly constructed file name

Comment: thank you for your help here and also detailed description of what each piece of code does to the output! It works perfectly concatenating all the files!