# How to rev & cut (using the same pattern) a list of strings in a single line?

Tags: bash, find, cut

I intend to write a script that gathers files based on their filename prefix, and tar them together (when they share the same prefix).
I have no list of the prefix, and I need to build it from the filenames themselves.

Files have names like:

```
top-1.parquet
top-2.parquet
side-1.parquet
side-2.parquet
bot-tom-1.parquet
bot-tom-2.parquet
right-left-1.parquet
right-left-2.parquet
```

To do so, I started with this script.

```sh
RMT_PATH_DATA='/home/me/Documents/code/data'

while IFS= read -r -d $'\n' root_name
do
    # Work out tar here
    echo "Working file $root_name"
    ls "$root_name"*.parquet
done < <(find "$RMT_PATH_DATA" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.parquet" -print0 | rev | cut -f 2- -d '-' | rev | sort -zu)
```

(this script is more or less copied from the [retained answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652718/how-to-concatenate-files-that-have-the-same-beginning-of-a-name) on SO)

The logic of the last line is to revert the list of filenames retrieved with `find`, and trim the digit of the filename and the prefix.
The trimming is made by first reversing the filename, using `cut` starting on the 2nd field on reversed name (`-` is the field delimiter, and it can be used a variable number of times in the prefix itself).

My trouble appears with the `rev` and `cut` commands.
The `find` commands outputs the list of parquet files in the `data` directory, but `rev` and `cut` appear processing only the 1st item of the list, discarding the other items.

Please, how can I make them processing the full list?

Thanks for your help!
Bests

PS: I have not built the `tar` part yet, and only do an `echo` and `ls` to check what is being processed in the loop. Only one iteration is currently done because of the raised trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is the -print0 option that you use in find.  Then the delemiter between the found items is the NUL and not the newline. In [How to concatenate files that have the same beginning of a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652718/how-to-concatenate-files-that-have-the-same-beginning-of-a-name) the have used cut with the -z option, which is the corresponding of -print0. The rev command does not have  an option to use the NUL delemiter as far as i can see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as highlighted by @Oliver Gaida, there is a trouble with `print0`.

I ended up using following code, that appears to work (tar command included :))

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d $'\n' full_name
do
  find "$RMT_PATH_DATA" -maxdepth 1 -name "$(basename "$full_name")*.parquet" -type f -size +1k -mmin $MOD_TIME | xargs -n 1 basename | tar -cf "${full_name}.tar" -C "$RMT_PATH_DATA" -T - --remove-files
done < <(find "$RMT_PATH_DATA" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.parquet" -type f -size +1k -mmin $MOD_TIME | rev | cut -f 2- -d '-' | rev | sort -u)
```

Have to run that with ssh now...